# How to get the onChange property of AntDesign Cascader component to work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to use the Cascader component of AntDesign and handle its values on change. However, I get an error on the part where I assign an onChange function to the onChange property of the component. Here's the code extracted from the website of AntDesign:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Cascader } from 'antd';

interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  children?: Option[];
}

const options: Option[] = [
  {
    value: 'zhejiang',
    label: 'Zhejiang',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'hangzhou',
        label: 'Hangzhou',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'xihu',
            label: 'West Lake',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 'jiangsu',
    label: 'Jiangsu',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'nanjing',
        label: 'Nanjing',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'zhonghuamen',
            label: 'Zhong Hua Men',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const onChange = (value: string[]) => {
  console.log(value);
};

// Just show the latest item.
const displayRender = (labels: string[]) => labels[labels.length - 1];

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Cascader
    options={options}
    expandTrigger="hover"
    displayRender={displayRender}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);

export default App;
```

Here is the error:

```
Type '(value: string[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'OnSingleChange<DefaultOptionType> | OnMultipleChange<DefaultOptionType> | undefined'.
  Type '(value: string[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'OnSingleChange<DefaultOptionType>'.
    Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'SingleValueType' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Cascader.d.ts(70, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PropsWithChildren<CascaderProps<Option>> & { ref?: Ref<CascaderRef> | undefined; })'
```

I don't know what anything else to try to solve the problem since the code itself already came from the official website and I expect it to work.

Comment: Which example? This example works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/imf3cv?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I'm wondering why the example works on there but not on my computer. I tried using the onChange property on any other input types such us Number, Datepicker, and Text area. They all work fine. The error only comes out on the Cascader input type. My antd version is 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure why this worked, maybe someone else can provide a reason but I added a number type and the error is gone.

```
const onChange = (value: (string | number)[]) => {
  console.log(value);
};
```